# How to make a gridview for all devices in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, user-interface, dart

I have a regular GridView with an image and a text below it in my app. I recently used device preview to see how it appears on other devices and it appears very different on tablets vs on small phones. Is it possible to make a single grid with even spacing on all devices so that it doesn't differ so much?
This is my code:

```
GridView.builder(
              gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                crossAxisCount: 3,
                mainAxisSpacing: 15.0,
                crossAxisSpacing: 10.0,
                childAspectRatio: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width /
                    (MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 1.92),
              ),
              itemCount: 100,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Expanded(
                      child: ClipRRect(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(15.0)),
                        child: GridTile(
                          child: Image.network(
                            'https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/proxy/DC95dZwFErJk5toYcgiDngZbOnQuvHsZHMe7hIUol_dlykLi3xgJljZlljxJJU2WM2jACnOpHXjidqamjHWIOQ6DrABhkXahUzKwQSIC9dXPGJb8NhqJiLxRNcEEQseKAH9DlEHYgBEsMtY8pqubmv3HU2L15i5CJyuGs5XFhw',
                            height: 150,
                            fit: BoxFit.fill,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 2.0),
                        child: RichText(
                          overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                          maxLines: 1,
                          text: TextSpan(
                            text: 'Hello',
                            style: kTasksStyle.copyWith(
                              color: kDarkBlue,
                              fontSize: getValueForScreenType<double>(
                                  context: context, mobile: 14, tablet: 20),
                            ),
                          ),
                        )),
                  ],
                );
              },
            ),
```

This is how it appears on a small android phone (320x560):
[image]

And this is how it appears on a tablet:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please correct me if I misunderstand you question or you need clarification.

I think you problem here is due to the fact you did not use media query on the `mainAxisSpacing` and the `crossAxisSpacing` so the larger the device you use the larger the space between the grid items would become. You also seemed to do the same thing with the `Text`.

Comment: I tried this but it just makes the spacing even more unpredictable and weird. Is there anything else you can suggest?

Comment: I'll test it out a bit later and see if I can find a solid solution. :)